# NGINX i18n without changing URL

Tags: nginx, internationalization, angular-i18n

I wonder how to redirect traffic based on browser language using NGINX **without changing the URL**.

Here is my file structure:

```
 en
|-  index.html
 fr
|-  index.html
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://dev.to/angular/deploying-an-i18n-angular-app-with-angular-cli-2fb9), which is working as expected e.g. `/home` is redirected to `/en/home`.

Now is it possible to do the same without changing the address bar URL?

Here is my NGINX config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location /en/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/en/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /en/index.html;
  }
  location /fr/ {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/html/fr/;
    try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /fr/index.html;
  }

  set $first_language $http_accept_language;
  if ($http_accept_language ~* '^(.+?),') {
    set $first_language $1;
  }

  set $language_suffix 'en';
  if ($first_language ~* 'fr') {
    set $language_suffix 'fr';
  }

  location / {
    rewrite ^/$ /$language_suffix/index.html permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try: `rewrite...last` instead of `rewrite...permanent`.

Comment: @RichardSmith It's not working. It seems like it's because Angular CLI change the HTML base href to /en/ or /fr/ and this behavior can't be changed. Is there a NGINX way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the file structure to (en as default locale):

```
 index.html
 fr
|-  index.html
```

It works on Node.js localhost for me, but I have not try it on production server.